# aws amplify auth custom signup can not map undefined

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Learning to use aws amplify and i want to override their signup component following an example i found, but i keep getting the undefined error below. The cognito user pool requires a user sign up with an email as the username, and name attribute.

Here is my signup component.

```
import React from "react";
import { SignUp } from "aws-amplify-react";

export class CustomSignUp extends SignUp {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this._validAuthStates = ["signUp"];
      this.state = {
        userName: 'test',
        password: 'MyTest123!',
        email: 'test@gmail.com',
        phoneNumber: '1231231234'
      };
    }

    handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state);
        const response = await super.signUp({
            username: this.state.email, 
            password: this.state.password, 
            attributes: {
              email: this.state.email, 
              phone_number: this.state.phone,
              name: this.state.userName
            }
          });
        console.log(response);
    }

    showComponent(theme) {
      return (
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.userName}
            onChange={event => this.setState({ userName: event.target.value })}
            placeholder="Enter your username"
            required
            />
            <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.password}
            onChange={event => this.setState({ password: event.target.value })}
            placeholder="Enter your password"
            required
            />
            <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.email}
            onChange={event => this.setState({ email: event.target.value })}
            placeholder="Enter your email"
            required
            />
            <button>Sign up</button>
        </form>
      );
    }
  }
```

Error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
at CustomSignUp.SignUp.validate (SignUp.js:94)
at CustomSignUp.SignUp.signUp (SignUp.js:203)
```

Comment: I'm trying to solve the same problem.  Did you figure out how to get the signUpFields passed to the parent SignUp component?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. Declaring `this.signupFields` directly inside the constructor on the CustomSignUp class seems to be the only way I could fix it. It seems that this doesn't get passed down in the props from the parent class.

```
export class CustomSignUp extends SignUp {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this._validAuthStates = ["signUp"];
      this.state = {
        userName: 'test',
        password: 'MyTest123!',
        email: 'test@gmail.com',
        phoneNumber: '1231231234'
      };

      this.signUpFields = [
      {
        label: 'Username',
        key: 'username',
        required: true,
        displayOrder: 1,
        type: 'string'
      },
      {
        label: 'Email',
        key: 'email',
        required: true,
        displayOrder: 2,
        type: 'string'
      },
      {
        label: 'Password',
        key: 'password',
        required: true,
        displayOrder: 3,
        type: 'password'
      },
      {
        label: 'Phone Number',
        key: 'phone_number',
        required: false,
        displayOrder: 4,
        type: 'string'
      }
    ];

    }
```

I'm not sure if Phone Number's needed, but I noticed the defaultSignUpFields variable has that set to required=true, so I deliberately override it here.